# Splitting an object by commas and then adding this to a hbs file

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to dynamically add buttons with their own links and titles. So in theory someone would be able to enter links (separated) by commas and their titles underneath (not the best solution but it's just for now). At the moment the page is showing up with 1 button with 2 links and 2 titles added to it (shown in screenshot)

router.js

```
router.get('/products/:permalinkSlug', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const permalinkJob = req.params.permalinkSlug
    const post = await postTools.getPostByPermalinkProducts(permalinkJob)
    post.authorName = (await postTools.getAuthorById(post.author_id)).real_name
    post.site_url = process.env.HOSTNAME


    post.poster = {
     "link": post.product_link.split(','),
      "title": post.link_title.split(',')
    }
```

HBS

```
{{#with poster}}
                  <a class="product_links_href" href="{{link}}" target="_blank">{{title}}</a>
              {{/with}}
```

What's being returned

```
RowDataPacket {
      id: 1,
      name: null,
      extract: null,
      icon_image: null,
      title: 'Product1',
      permalink_slug: 'product1',
      content: '<p>How can you two... Don\'t Google the question, Moss! Yeah, you need to turn it on... uh, the button turns it on. So, remember the new number! 0118 999! 88199, 9119 725! ... 3! Yeah, you need to turn it on... uh, the button turns it on. Hello? I\'ve had a bit of a tumble. Dear Sir stroke Madam, I am writing to inform you of a fire which has broken out at the premises of...</p>',
      author_id: 1,
      tags: '',
      last_modified_date: 2018-07-09T09:47:09.000Z,
      publish_date: 2018-07-06T08:30:12.000Z,
      status: 'published',
      feature_image: 33,
      product_image: '49',
      product_href: null,
      undefined: null,
      product_link: 'https://bbc.co.uk, https://google.com',
      link_title: 'Discover more, Learn More',
      authorName: 'Admin',
      site_url: 'http://localhost:3000',
      poster: 
       { link: [ 'https://bbc.co.uk', ' https://google.com' ],
         title: [ 'Discover more', ' Learn More' ] } }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [the `each` helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) to loop over the options, but it’ll be a bit awkward with the object of arrays that you have now. You should instead have an array of objects:

```
const SEPARATOR = /\s*,\s*/;

router.get('/products/:permalinkSlug', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const permalinkJob = req.params.permalinkSlug;
    const post = await postTools.getPostByPermalinkProducts(permalinkJob);
    post.authorName = (await postTools.getAuthorById(post.author_id)).real_name
    post.site_url = process.env.HOSTNAME

    const links = post.product_link.split(SEPARATOR);
    const titles = post.link_title.split(SEPARATOR);

    const combined = links.map((link) => {
      return {
        link,
        title: titles.shift(),
      };
    });

    post.poster = combined;
```

Then your template can loop over these:

```
{{#each poster}}
    <a class="product_links_href" href="{{this.link}}" target="_blank">{{this.title}}</a>
{{/each}}
```